# Unable to uncheck input type checkbox in mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a responsive table, I have the most part of this down, I am trying to make it accordion like when viewed on smaller resolutions, unfortunately when the checkbox is clicked, it will not uncheck (retract). I'm probably missing something very obvious or doing something completely wrong. I've tried using JS to create the function. Could someone please point me in the right direction with this?

```js
$(function() {

  $(".close").on('change', function(e) {
    var el = $(this); {
      $(".close").not(el).prop('checked', false);
    }

  });

});
```

```css
body {
  background: #cacaca;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.caption {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #64e0ef;
  height: 55px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 55px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header-row {
  background: #8b8b8b;
  color: #fff;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 6px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  text-align: center;
}

.primary {
  text-align: left;
}

input[type="radio"],
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  body {
    padding: 0;
  }
  #table {
    display: block;
    margin: 44px 0 0 0;
  }
  .caption {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    height: 44px;
    line-height: 44px;
    z-index: 5;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #999;
  }
  .row {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
  .header-row {
    display: none;
  }
  .cell {
    display: block;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .primary:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 18px;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid #ccc;
  }
  .cell:nth-of-type(n+2) {
    display: none;
  }
  input[type="radio"],
  input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 99%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  input[type="radio"]:checked,
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
    z-index: -1;
  }
  input[type="radio"]:checked~.cell,
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.cell {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  }
  input[type="radio"]:checked~.cell:nth-of-type(n+2),
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.cell:nth-of-type(n+2) {
    background: #e0e0e0;
  }
  input[type="radio"]:checked~.cell:nth-of-type(n+2):before,
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.cell:nth-of-type(n+2):before {
    content: attr(data-label);
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    background: #999;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
  }
  input[type="radio"]:checked~.primary,
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.primary {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #999;
  }
  input[type="radio"]:checked~.primary:after,
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.primary:after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 18px;
    top: 22px;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #ccc;
    z-index: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="caption">Main Title</div>
<div id="table">
  <div class="header-row row">
    <span class="cell primary">
      <!--stuff here to add text in first prim cell --></span>
    <span class="cell">Developer</span>
    <span class="cell">Foundation</span>
    <span class="cell">Accelerator</span>
    <span class="cell">Enterprise</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" name="expand" class="close">
    <span class="cell primary" data-label="Category">Item 1</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" name="expand" class="close">
    <span class="cell primary" data-label="Category">Item 2</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" name="expand" class="close">
    <span class="cell primary" data-label="Category">Item 3</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" name="expand" class="close">
    <span class="cell primary" data-label="Category">Item 4</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" name="expand" class="close">
    <span class="cell primary" data-label="Category">Item 5</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" name="expand" class="close">
    <span class="cell primary" data-label="Category">Item 6</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is code here `var el = $(this); {` doing?

Comment: just wrap the content of the cell in a label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works like an accordion, meaning if you open another item, the other ones are collapsed. If you want to also close the active one on reclick/retap on it, you need to trigger the click on the checkbox.

Add the following to your JavaScript code and it will fix your issue.

`$('.primary').on('click', function() {
  $(this).prev().trigger('click');
})`

As an explanation as to why it works the first time, it's because you actually click the checkbox the first time, but after that, the primary cell comes over and captures the pointer events.

Comment: Another fix is to turn `input[type="checkbox"]:checked { z-index: -1 }` to `z-index: 1` and it will capture the click event without any additional JavaScript help.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix it adding a new input checkbox before first div row. Check this:

```js
$(function() {
    $(".close").on('click', function(e) {
        $(".close").not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #cacaca;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.caption {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #64e0ef;
  height: 55px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 55px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header-row {
  background: #8b8b8b;
  color: #fff;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 6px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  text-align: center;
}

.primary {
  text-align: left;
}

input[type="radio"],
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  body {
    padding: 0;
  }
  #table {
    display: block;
    margin: 44px 0 0 0;
  }
  .caption {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    height: 44px;
    line-height: 44px;
    z-index: 5;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #999;
  }
  .row {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
  .header-row {
    display: none;
  }
  .cell {
    display: block;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .primary:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 18px;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid #ccc;
  }
  .cell:nth-of-type(n+2) {
    display: none;
  }
  input[type="radio"],
  input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 99%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  input[type="radio"]:checked,
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
    z-index: -1;
  }
  input[type="radio"]:checked~.cell,
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.cell {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  }
  input[type="radio"]:checked~.cell:nth-of-type(n+2),
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.cell:nth-of-type(n+2) {
    background: #e0e0e0;
  }
  input[type="radio"]:checked~.cell:nth-of-type(n+2):before,
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.cell:nth-of-type(n+2):before {
    content: attr(data-label);
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    background: #999;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
  }
  input[type="radio"]:checked~.primary,
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.primary {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #999;
  }
  input[type="radio"]:checked~.primary:after,
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.primary:after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 18px;
    top: 22px;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #ccc;
    z-index: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="caption">Main Title</div>
<div id="table">
  <div class="header-row row">
    <span class="cell primary">
      <!--stuff here to add text in first prim cell --></span>
    <span class="cell">Developer</span>
    <span class="cell">Foundation</span>
    <span class="cell">Accelerator</span>
    <span class="cell">Enterprise</span>
  </div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="expand" class="close">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" name="expand" class="close">
    <span class="cell primary" data-label="Category">Item 1</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" name="expand" class="close">
    <span class="cell primary" data-label="Category">Item 2</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" name="expand" class="close">
    <span class="cell primary" data-label="Category">Item 3</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" name="expand" class="close">
    <span class="cell primary" data-label="Category">Item 4</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" name="expand" class="close">
    <span class="cell primary" data-label="Category">Item 5</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" name="expand" class="close">
    <span class="cell primary" data-label="Category">Item 6</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a label around the content.

```js
$(function() {

  $(".close").on('change', function(e) {
    var el = $(this); {
      $(".close").not(el).prop('checked', false);
    }

  });

});
```

```css
body {
  background: #cacaca;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.caption {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #64e0ef;
  height: 55px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 55px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header-row {
  background: #8b8b8b;
  color: #fff;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 6px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  text-align: center;
}

.primary {
  text-align: left;
}

input[type="radio"],
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  body {
    padding: 0;
  }
  #table {
    display: block;
    margin: 44px 0 0 0;
  }
  .caption {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    height: 44px;
    line-height: 44px;
    z-index: 5;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #999;
  }
  .row {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
  .header-row {
    display: none;
  }
  .cell {
    display: block;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .primary:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 18px;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid #ccc;
  }
  .cell:nth-of-type(n+2) {
    display: none;
  }
  input[type="radio"],
  input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 99%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  input[type="radio"]:checked,
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
    z-index: -1;
  }
  input[type="radio"]:checked~.cell,
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.cell {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  }
  input[type="radio"]:checked~.cell:nth-of-type(n+2),
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.cell:nth-of-type(n+2) {
    background: #e0e0e0;
  }
  input[type="radio"]:checked~.cell:nth-of-type(n+2):before,
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.cell:nth-of-type(n+2):before {
    content: attr(data-label);
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    background: #999;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
  }
  input[type="radio"]:checked~.primary,
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.primary {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #999;
  }
  input[type="radio"]:checked~.primary:after,
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.primary:after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 18px;
    top: 22px;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #ccc;
    z-index: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="caption">Main Title</div>
<div id="table">
  <div class="header-row row">
    <span class="cell primary">
      <!--stuff here to add text in first prim cell --></span>
    <span class="cell">Developer</span>
    <span class="cell">Foundation</span>
    <span class="cell">Accelerator</span>
    <span class="cell">Enterprise</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row"><label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="expand" class="close">
    <span class="cell primary" data-label="Category">Item 1</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
</label>
  </div>
  <div class="row"><label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="expand" class="close">
    <span class="cell primary" data-label="Category">Item 2</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
</label>
  </div>
  <div class="row"><label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="expand" class="close">
    <span class="cell primary" data-label="Category">Item 3</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="row"><label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="expand" class="close">
    <span class="cell primary" data-label="Category">Item 4</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="row"><label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="expand" class="close">
    <span class="cell primary" data-label="Category">Item 5</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="row"><label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="expand" class="close">
    <span class="cell primary" data-label="Category">Item 6</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span>
    <span class="cell" data-label="Category">Sub Item</span></label>
  </div>
</div>
```